# wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) on creating a session login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, authentication

Hi I'm getting this error on my rails app. I'm new in Rails.

> ArgumentError in SessionsController#create wrong number of arguments
>   (0 for 1)

Extracted source (around line #13):

**Here is my User model:**

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  attr_accessor :password
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  # devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  #        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,               type: String
  field :username,            type: String
  field :password_digest,     type: String
  has_secure_password

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   type: String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, type: Time

  ## Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, type: Time

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String

  ## Confirmable
  field :confirmation_token,   type: String
  field :confirmed_at,         type: DateTime
  field :confirmation_sent_at, type: DateTime
  field :confirmation_resent_at, type: DateTime
  # field :unconfirmed_email,    type: String # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # field :failed_attempts, type: Integer, default: 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # field :unlock_token,    type: String # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  field :locked,       type: Boolean, default: false
  field :locked_at,       type: DateTime

  ## Identifications
  field :is_patient, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :is_physician, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :is_admin, type: Boolean, default: false



  # scope :physician, ->{ where(is_physician: true) }
  # scope :patient, ->{ where(is_patient: true) }
  # scope :admin, ->{ where(is_admin: true) }

  # def to_key
  #   if key = super
  #     key = key.map(&:to_s)
  #   end
  #   key
  # end
end
```

Here is my **controller** where the error says line 13 which is this line

```
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password_digest])
```

**Sessions controller:**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    layout 'login_layout'

    def index

    end

    def create

        user = User.where(username: params[:session][:username]).first
        # abort(YAML::dump(user))
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password_digest])
            redirectUrl = nil
            # check if the user is an admin
            if user.is_admin == true

                if user.locked == true
                    flash[:danger] = 'You no longer have admin access! Please Contact System Admin for re activation'
                else
                    flash[:success] = 'Welcome ' + user.username
                    redirectUrl = '/admin'
                end
            # check if the user is an physicians
            elsif user.is_physician == true
                redirectUrl = '/physicians'
            # check if the user is an patients
            elsif user.is_patient == true
                redirectUrl = '/user'
            # in no usertype found
            else
                flash[:danger] = 'User type not set. Please Contact Administrator via mail medzoc@support.com'
                redirect_to '/login'
            end
            sign_in user
            redirect_to redirectUrl
        else
            # abort('fail')
            flash[:danger] = 'Invalid Username or Password combination' # Not quite right!
            redirect_to '/login'
        end

    end

    def destroy
        sign_out #helper function 
        redirect_to '/login'
    end

end
```

**Here is my route:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # root Routes
  root 'pages#home'

  #index Routes
  get 'login' => 'sessions#index'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

I'm not sure what's wrong. I'm just trying to log-in and authenticate in a specific controller to avoid giving access to all of my controllers and pages

Comment: What is `params` on top of `create` action? Please add `logger.debug params` after `def create` and let us know the output. And What is `User#authenticate` method?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that `params[:session][:password_digest]` is nil. I would install either the pry gem or the better_errors gem so that you can inspect what is going on with a console.